# Worklight adapter deployment using command line

Tags: ant, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any way to deploy a worklight adapter using a command line instead of using the worklight console? (As my worklight server is installed on WAS, a wsadmin command or something like that ...).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ANT Tasks described [in the documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_for_building_and_dep.html). Note that the **Ant tasks are supplied with the Enterprise and Consumer editions.** Not the free developer edition.

### Deploying an adapter

The Ant task for deploying an adapter has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project base="." default="target-name">
<target name="target-name">
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
<classpath>
<pathelement location="path_to_worklight-ant-platform.version>.jar" />
</classpath>
</taskdef>
<adapter-deployer worklightserverhost="http://server-address:port" deployable="myAdapter.adapter" />
</target>
</project>
```

The  element has the following attributes:

- The worklightserverhost attribute specifies the full URL of your Worklight server.
- The deployable attribute specifies the .adapter file to deploy.
  If you must deploy more than one .adapter file, add an  element for each file.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to install Ant or copy extra Worklight build tools jars use the unix curl utility:

sometimes using cURL will cause an java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in deployment but this due to  bad form upload. the correct format is here:
lets assume the binaries are located on /tmp/workspace6.3/proj1/bin/ and the Worklight admin username and password is 'admin' (on a local worklight server)
using the curl unix utility we can deploy

### adapters:

`curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  -F "file=@/tmp/workspace6.3/proj1/bin/sampleAdapter.adapter" --user admin:admin -H "Accept: application/json"  http://localhost:10080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/proj1/adapters`

### wlapps:

`curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  -F "file=@/tmp/workspace6.3/proj1/bin/app1-all.wlapp" --user admin:admin -H "Accept: application/json"  http://localhost:10080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/proj1/applications`

the only problem here is that these POST URLs are compatible with Worklight v6.3-v7 and they might change across future major versions, so read the documentation for release admin REST API to get the correct URLs .